# Replacing a value with 0 based on condition in same row

Tags: r, dataframe, replace

I have had a read through similar questions, but they all seemed to be far more complex than mine and I couldn't transfer this knowledge to my case.

I have this dataframe ('EUETS_ver`)

```
country year emissions iso2      sector
Austria 2005  33373156   AT   regulated
Austria 2005  33373156   AT unregulated
Austria 2005  33373156   AT       total
Belgium 2005  55363232   BE   regulated
Belgium 2005  55363232   BE unregulated
Belgium 2005  55363232   BE       total
Cyprus 2005   5078877    CY   regulated
Cyprus 2005   5078877    CY unregulated
Cyprus 2005   5078877    CY       total
```

I want to replace the value in `EUETS_ver$emissions` with 0 where it `EUETS$sector` is `unregulated`.

I want to get this:

```
country year emissions iso2      sector
Austria 2005  33373156   AT   regulated
Austria 2005  0          AT unregulated
Austria 2005  33373156   AT       total
Belgium 2005  55363232   BE   regulated
Belgium 2005  0          BE unregulated
Belgium 2005  55363232   BE       total
Cyprus 2005   5078877    CY   regulated
Cyprus 2005   0          CY unregulated
Cyprus 2005   5078877    CY       total
```

I know this should be easy, but it isn't for me...

Thanks in advance

nordsee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
EUETS_ver$emissions[EUETS_ver$sector=="unregulated"]<-0
```

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I needed